# Using Nested SQL Queries with SFMC Data Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm looking to write a query (in SFMC) that pulls counts of Emails Sent and Unique Opens from data views -- and then eventually a calculated field for Open Rate -- filtered based on Domain and JobID. But I can't figure out how to structure nested queries to get it quite right. Anyone able to assist? I'm looking for something like the following, except I know my third line is all wrong...

```
SELECT s.JobID, 
COUNT(s.SubscriberKey) as SentCount,
(SELECT COUNT(o.SubscriberKey) as OpenTemp FROM _Open o WHERE o.IsUnique = 'True') as OpenCount
FROM _Sent s
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
WHERE s.JobID IN ('111111','222222')
AND s.Domain = 'gmail.com'
GROUP BY s.JobID
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do -- beyond "the third line is all wrong" -- would all help.

Comment: Sure thing, sorry. JobID will be a 6-digit number indicating the email campaign. SubscriberKey will be a unique ID for each member. So what I'm looking for is, basically, a table with a list of JobIDs, and then counts of Emails Sent and Unique Opens for each.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a shot. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT s.JobID, COUNT(DISTINCT s.SubscriberKey) as SentCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.SubscriberKey) as OpenCount
FROM _Sent s LEFT JOIN
     _Open o
     ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
WHERE s.JobID IN ('111111', '222222') AND s.Domain = 'gmail.com'
GROUP BY s.JobID;
```